# rails model helper class not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Game model, and in my model, I want to use a helper class, GameBoard. I tried to create game_board.rb in app/helpers, and then use it in my game model.

```
#game_board.rb
class GameBoard
  def initialize(foo)
     #stufff
  end
end

#in after_intialize in game.rb
@board = new GameBoard(foo)
```

However, when trying to create a game, it fails to create the GameBoard, saying

NoMethodError: undefined method `GameBoard' for Game:0x00000005309df0

I tried requiring game_board.rb at the top of the file and that didn't work. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All files from app/ directory automatically loaded by Rails. So, for instantiate a new object you should use (http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/intro.html )

```
GameBoard.new(foo)
```

instead of

```
new GameBoard(foo)
```

Comment: oh ok I thought that was just for ActiveRecord models, i didn't realize that was normal ruby syntax. Got it. Thanks.